# Detect user input in UITextView (besides delegation)

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm subclassing `UITextView` and want to handle user input inside it. It's not an option to take advantage of delegation because it should be possible to set a delegate to something different. Anyone knows how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for this. You can use `UITextViewTextDidChange` notification.

```
class UITextViewPlus: UITextView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textChange(_:)), name: .UITextViewTextDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    func textChange(_ sender: NSNotification)  {
        guard let textView = sender.object as? UITextViewPlus, textView == self else {
            // ignoring text change of any other UITextView
            return
        }

        // do something
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }    
}
```

**Note:** Just keep in mind `UITextViewTextDidChange` notification is posted for any text change in any `UITextView`.